# Is it possible to Sum and Average outside the columns and rows of a pivot table in Crystal?

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I am creating a report in Crystal 11.  I have two tables; County and Redemption.

The columns I am using in Redemption are;

- CodeBudget
- CodeEntity
- CodeCounty
- CollectYr
- Redemption_Amount

The columns I am using in County are;

- CodeCounty
- Name

I have grouped them by CodeCounty and then by CodeEntity.  I have then created a pivot table within each Entity.  The pivot table columns are by CollectYr and the row are by CodeBudget.  I have then averaged by Redemption_Amount.  What I am attempting to do is to Average by budget by year and then get an average over the five years for each row.  But I also want to sum up by column.  Can anyone help or give me a better direction to go?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: A screenshot or two of what you have done so far would be helpful.